# How do you add Python syntax highlighting to a markdown file in vim?

Tags: vim, python

For Vim how do I add Python syntax highlighting to markdown files?

## Context

I'm creating a markdown document to show how to use a project. Fairly simple thing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result_queue = find_data_corruption()

    corruption_data = []
    while not result_queue.finished():
        if result_queue.has_results():
            corruption_data.append(result_queue.get())
```

So I'm sitting here writing example code in this markdown file and I really want syntax highlighting because I don't hate myself.

Comment: If you are running a recent version of Vim, it should be sufficient to add `let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['python']` in your ".vimrc". Also make sure to specify language in the beginning of the fenced block. (See [this page](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown) for additional info.)